# VSCode on Mac OS Monterey running python code to terminal instead of printing in output

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal

[image]
[image]
I installed VSCode through Homebrew and I'm writing a basic program. Anything I try to print prints to the terminal instead of output. I have no coderunner settings that I can find based on other questions similar to this

Tried to reinstall without homebrew, same issue. Anything I print prints to terminal and not output

Comment: what is the difference between both images

Comment: why do you look at the OUTPUT tab and not at the TERMINAL tab

Answer (score 0):

How did you run the python file?

[image]

1. You can use `Run Python File` button directly, you'll get the output in terminal.
2. If you use `Run Code` button, this is a function provided by code-runner extension. You have to add the following code to `settings.json`(Use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and search for **Preference: Open User Settings**) so that file will be run in terminal:

   "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,